# How to call a Java class from Java code using Runtime exec

Tags: java

I would like to know if there is a way to call a Java class from another. I implemented a testing code as follows using Runtime exec, calling "test.java" from "exec.java", but the exec calling won't execute. What is the problem in the code? Thanks.

test.java:

```
package com.example.exec;

public class test{

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

exec.java:

```
package com.example.exec;

public class exec {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            Process pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java test");
        } catch (Exception err) {
            System.out.println("Error!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you already compiled test?  C:/path javac test.java

Comment: In catch do err.printStackTrace to see the issue

Comment: Also: Why? You are be able to call `test.main(args)` directly.

Comment: Do you want execute this class only or any class

Comment: @6ton I've did err.printStackTrace(), but there are no errors.

Comment: @AliHelmy I want to execute the test.java only (from exec.java) as a new process.

Comment: @andrewdleach Yes, I complied the test.java.

Comment: You could just use a custom ClassLoader and Reflection to load and run the class from within the current jvm. But I'd recommend using ProcessBuilder of Runtime, it's more configurable

Comment: Thanks for all the replies! "Process pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java test"); " should be changed to "Process pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java com.example.exec.test");" with the whole path even test.java is in the same package with exec.java.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to run an arbitrary java class using `Runtime.exec`, you need a valid `java` command and to relay any output:

```
$ cat com/example/exec/exec.java
package com.example.exec;

public class exec {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
      Process pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java com.example.exec.test");
      byte[] buffer = new byte[65536];
      int length;
      while((length = pro.getInputStream().read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
        System.out.write(buffer, 0, length);
      }
    } catch (Exception err) {
      System.out.println("Error!");
      err.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

This should only ever be used by IDEs, build tools and similar. Java classes in the same program should never use `Runtime.exec` to invoke or communicate with each other.

Answer (score 0):

So you need first to compile the Java class from `.java` to `.class`:

```
 Process pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac -d . com/example/exec/test");
```

then execute the `.class`

```
 pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java com/example/exec/test");
```

Then read the input stream from the `process`